# Unable to start new fragment from a fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

Hello there i want to start the fragment "Add_Create_2" from "Add_Create" here is my code both the fragments are merged and the previous fragment is not removed and so thats why the next fragment is shown on the top of the first fragment when ever i click next button that is present in Add_Create Layout

```
Add_Create Java Code
  @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            FragmentTransaction transaction=getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.root,new Add_Create_2())
                    ;
            transaction.addToBackStack(null);

            transaction.commit();

        }

Add_Create XML Code
      <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"

android:fillViewport="true">

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/root"

    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:text="General Information"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="151dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="15dp"
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:hint="Enter Announcement Name"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/lightblue"
        android:textColorHint="#3F51B5"
        android:textColor="#3F51B5"
        android:id="@+id/announcement_name"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:hint="Enter Description"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/lightblue"
        android:textColorHint="#3F51B5"
        android:textColor="#3F51B5"
        android:id="@+id/description"
        android:maxLines="4"
        android:lines="2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/announcement_name"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/lightblue"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:hint="Enter Price"
        android:textColorHint="#3F51B5"
        android:textColor="#3F51B5"
        android:id="@+id/price"
        android:layout_below="@+id/description"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
    <Spinner
    android:id="@+id/duration"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:entries="@array/items"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"

        android:layout_below="@+id/price"
    android:prompt="@string/duration" />

    <TextView
        android:text="Choose Image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="151dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="15dp"
        android:id="@+id/image1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/duration" />
    <Button
        android:text="Choose"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/duration"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="21dp"
        android:id="@+id/Image_Picker"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:layout_marginTop="20px"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:layout_marginLeft="150dp"
        android:background="@drawable/buttons"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/image1" />
    <TextView
        android:text="Location"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="151dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="15dp"
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/image1"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:hint="Enter Location"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/lightblue"
        android:textColorHint="#3F51B5"
        android:textColor="#3F51B5"
        android:id="@+id/room_address"
        android:maxLines="4"
        android:lines="2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
       <Button
        android:text="Next"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/room_address"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/Submit_Room_Information"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
           android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
           android:background="@drawable/buttons" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

```
Add_Create_2 Java Code
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.create_add_2, container, false);
}

Add_Create_2 XML Code
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>


 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<TextView
    android:text="Availability"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="151dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="15dp"
    android:id="@+id/textView5"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />
<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/checkbox_alltheday"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView5"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:text="All the Day" />
<TextView
    android:text="Start Time"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="151dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="15dp"
    android:id="@+id/textView7"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/checkbox_alltheday"
    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:textSize="20dp" />
<TextView
    android:text="Services"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="151dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="15dp"
    android:id="@+id/textView9"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView8"

    android:textStyle="bold" />

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/service_bathroom"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView9"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:text="Bathroom" />

    android:text="" />
<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/service_other"
    android:layout_marginTop="17dp"

    android:backgroundTint="@color/lightblue"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:hint="Other"
    android:textColorHint="#3F51B5"
    android:textColor="#3F51B5"
    android:id="@+id/other"
    android:layout_below="@+id/service_parking"
    />
```

[image: here is the result]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Transitions should be handled by Activity not by fragment**. When you get the event to change the fragment then give this information to your activity, after that  activity should change the fragment. 
i.e. Make a function in activity which performs the transitions and call that function from the fragment whenever required. 
You can all the method of activity either by creating an **interface** or **typecasting getActivity()** method in your activity class type to call the method

This should fix your code
MainActivity xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="yourapp.com.fragments.MainActivity">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/root"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"></FrameLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    FrameLayout root;
    AddCreate firstFragment;
    AddCreate2 secondFragment;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        firstFragment = new AddCreate();
        secondFragment = new AddCreate2();
        showFragment(0);

    }

    public void showFragment(int which) {
        android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        switch (which) {
            case 0:
                transaction.replace(R.id.root,firstFragment);
                break;
            case 1:
                transaction.replace(R.id.root,secondFragment);
                break;
        }
        transaction.addToBackStack(null);
        transaction.commit();
    }
}
```

AddCreate.java

```
public class AddCreate extends Fragment {


    public AddCreate() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       View v =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.add__create, container, false);
        v.findViewById(R.id.Submit_Room_Information).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                ((MainActivity)getActivity()).showFragment(1);
            }
        });
        return v;
    }

}
```

AddCreate.xml

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context="pantherstechnik.com.fragments.fragment.AddCreate">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:text="General Information"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="151dp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="15dp" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/announcement_name"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:hint="Enter Announcement Name"
            android:textColor="#3F51B5"
            android:textColorHint="#3F51B5" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/description"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/announcement_name"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"

            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:hint="Enter Description"
            android:lines="2"
            android:maxLines="4"
            android:textColor="#3F51B5"
            android:textColorHint="#3F51B5" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/price"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"

            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/description"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:hint="Enter Price"
            android:textColor="#3F51B5"
            android:textColorHint="#3F51B5" />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/duration"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:layout_below="@+id/price"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"

            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/image1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/duration"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:text="Choose Image"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="151dp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="15dp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/Image_Picker"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/duration"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:layout_marginLeft="150dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="21dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20px"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/image1"

            android:text="Choose"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/image1"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:text="Location"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="151dp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="15dp" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/room_address"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"

            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:hint="Enter Location"
            android:lines="2"
            android:maxLines="4"
            android:textColor="#3F51B5"
            android:textColorHint="#3F51B5" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/Submit_Room_Information"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/room_address"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:text="Next"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

AddCreate2 xml

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="pantherstechnik.com.fragments.fragment.AddCreate2">
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TextView
        android:text="Availability"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="151dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="15dp"
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkbox_alltheday"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:text="All the Day" />
    <TextView
        android:text="Start Time"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="151dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="15dp"
        android:id="@+id/textView7"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/checkbox_alltheday"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:textSize="20dp" />
    <TextView
        android:text="Services"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="151dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="15dp"
        android:id="@+id/textView9"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView8"

        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/service_bathroom"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView9"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:text="Bathroom" />

    android:text="" />
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/service_other"
        android:layout_marginTop="17dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:hint="Other"
        android:textColorHint="#3F51B5"
        android:textColor="#3F51B5"
        android:id="@+id/other"
        android:layout_below="@+id/service_parking"
        />
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

AddCreate2.java

```
public class AddCreate2 extends Fragment {


    public AddCreate2() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.add_create2, container, false);
        return v;
    }

}
```

Comment: You are suggesting me that i should make a function in my activity and then call it from the fragment button click?

Comment: Just like this?
Activity a1= new Activity();
a1.method()

Comment: no when you are in fragment class you have getActivity() method. typecase this method e.g.
((MyActivity) getActivity()).methodName();

Comment: i tried to run this but now the layout named "Add_Create_2" is not visible it shows empty screen

Comment: @AlicaCorwin please post the code you wrote in Activity

Comment: Here it is

    public void change()
    {
        FragmentTransaction transaction=getSupportFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.root,new Add_Create_2())
                ;
        transaction.addToBackStack(null);

        transaction.commit();

    }

Comment: @AlicaCorwin please check the edit. above code is working fine

Comment: Thank you sir i will look into it :)

Answer (score 0):

Add this on `onClick`:

```
            FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            transaction.replace(R.id.root,new Add_Create_2());     
            transaction.addToBackStack(null);
            transaction.commit();
```

Comment: Please add your logcat here, can't slove without seeing errors.